# Indentable and collapsable text and code snippets in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

Is it possible to define indentable and collapsable blocks of text or code (e.g. formatted with Syntax Highlight Geshi) in MediaWiki?

I have seen collapsable tables and lists in Wikipedia, and would like to apply the same concept to paragraphs and code snippets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you will need to have [ToggleDisplay](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aToggleDisplay) and [SyntaxHighlight GeSHi](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSyntaxHighlight_GeSHi) installed.

Then on your page add code like this (example for C++):

```
<toggledisplay showtext="this is the show text">
<syntaxhighlight lang="cpp">
 <Put the code here>
</syntaxhighlight>
</toggledisplay>
```

(See also: [Wikis and Wikipedia](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716))

Comment: Thanks also for the link to the Wikis and Wikipedia. I committed to it!

Comment: One quick question @Wikis Commit At Area 51, I am trying to indent the a collapsable block with `: <toggledisplay
<syntaxhighlight lang="cpp">
...
</toggledisplay>` 

but it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @AmV - you want to indent the code in the block or the whole block (including toggledisplay)?

Comment: @Wikis Commit At Area 51 - the whole block (including toggledisplay)

Comment: @AmV - do you have a public sandbox I can test on? Otherwise I'll have to get back to you.

Comment: I don't have a public sandbox at the moment, sorry :/. Thanks though for your help!

Comment: @AmV - actually, this is probably better posted as a whole different question. If you just add spaces at the start of the code lines, the code will be indented. Another option (for everything) is using blockquote: <blockquote style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 2em;"> <toggledisplay><all the code></toggledisplay></blockquote> - you can change or remove the border and play with the padding to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Wikis Commit At Area 51. I think I managed to make it work without blockquote. 

This seems to work: 
`: <toggledisplay showtext='Code'> <syntaxhighlight lang='MATLAB' enclose='div'>`

as long as I don't introduce a line break between the `toggledisplay` and `syntaxhighlight` tags